# What are some ways of doing inter-thread communication in JMeter?

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

I want to save a variable in thread_1, that is accessible to each thread afterwards

Answer (score 0):

The easiest is converting a variable into a property via [__setProperty() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__setProperty) on one thread.

Once done you will be able to access the value from all other threads via [__P() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__P)

[image]

---

If you need more complex criteria, like wait until the value is available or pass different values for different threads - it might be a better idea to consider using [Inter-Thread Communication Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-use-the-inter-thread-communication-plugin-in-jmeter/)